# Java rules for casting

Tags: java, casting, object

When can a certain object be cast into another object?  Does the casted object have to be a subtype of the other object?  I'm trying to figure out the rules...

**Edit**: I realized that I didn't explain my issue at all: basically I am casting an object to an interface type. However, at run-time, I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.  What needs to happen with my object so that I can cast it to this interface?  Does it have to implement it?

Thanks

Comment: In what situation do you actually need to explicitly cast an object to its interface type?

Comment: You have a very useful answer here.  I wish you would select it.

Answer (score 35):

In Java there are two types of reference variable casting:

- **Downcasting**: If you have a reference
  variable that refers to a subtype
  object, you can assign it to a
  reference variable of the subtype.
  You must make an explicit cast to do
  this, and the result is that you can
  access the subtype's members with
  this new reference variable.
- **Upcasting**: You can assign a reference
  variable to a supertype reference
  variable explicitly or implicitly.
  This is an inherently safe operation
  because the assignment restricts the
  access capabilities of the new
  variable.

**Yes**, you need to implement the interface *directly or indirectly* to enable assigning your class object reference to the interface type.

Comment: I'm not sure if you wrote this, copied it, or summarized, but it's excellent, made me realize what I was trying to do that made no sense.

Comment: examples would've been useful

Comment: Upvoted because of the human-written text, not some `B extends A` chatter.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose we want to cast d object to A,

A a = (C)d;

So internally 3 rules have been checked by Compiler and JVM.
**The compiler is checking first 2 rules at Compile time and JVM will check last one rule at Runtime.**

**Rule 1 (Compile time checking):**

> Type of 'd' and C must have some relation (child to parent or parent
>   to child or same time).If there is no relationship then we will get a
>   compile error(inconvertible types).

**Rule 2 (Compile time checking):**

> 'C' must be either same type or derived type(subclass) of 'A'
>   otherwise we will get a compile error(incompatible types).

**Rule 3 (Runtime Exception):**

> Runtime object type of 'd' must be same or derived a type of 'C'
>   otherwise we will get a runtime exception (ClassCastException
>   Exception).

Find following examples to get more idea,

```
String s = new String("hello"); StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer)s;  // Compile error : Invertible types because there is no relationship between.

Object o = new String("hello"); StringBuffer sb = (String)o;       // Compile error : Incompatible types because String is not child class of StringBuffer.

Object o = new String("hello"); StringBuffer sb = (StringBuffer)o; // Runtime Exception : ClassCastException because 'o' is string type and trying to cast into StingBuffer and there is no relationship between String and StringBuffer.
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an intuitive way of thinking about this - you're not changing an object with a cast, you're only doing something that would already be permitted if the type was known - inotherwords, you can only cast to a type that your object already is. So just look "up" the object chain to see what kinds apply to your object.

So you can cast to an interface *only* if it's defined somewhere higher up in the chain (e.g. if your classes parent implements it, etc. etc). It has to be explicit - from your question it sounds like you may be thinking that if you implement method "void foo()" then you should be able to cast to an interface that defines the method "void foo()" - this is sometimes described as ["duck typing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (if it quacks like a duck, it's a duck) but is not how java works.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
    public void run() {}
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
System.out.println((Runnable) foo);
```

But this will not:

```
class Bar {
    public void run() {}
}

Bar bar = new Bar();
System.out.println((Runnable) bar);
```

Because although `Bar` has a `run()` method that *could* implement `Runnable.run()`, `Bar` is not declared to implement `Runnable` so it cannot be cast to `Runnable`.

Java requires that you declare implemented interfaces by *name*.  It does not have [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), unlike some other languages such as [Python](http://www.python.org/) and [Go](http://golang.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can cast if the runtime type of an object is a subtype of what you're trying to cast it into.

EDIT:

Yes, the object that you're trying to cast will need to implement the interface in order for you to cast it successfully.

Comment: You're thinking about this entirely the wrong way. What you should be asking is "in what situations does it make sense to treat this `Foo` as an `IBar`?

Comment: what if the object I am trying to cast to that interface extends a class that implements the interface? will that avoid the run-time error?

Comment: oh ok..i tried to rephrase my original comment since it didnt really make sense at first try

Answer (score 2):

If:

```
interface MyInterface{}

class MyClass implements MyInterface{}
```

Then

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
MyInterface i = (MyInterface)m;
```

is possible.