# Confused about late binding/casting in Java

Tags: java, casting

```
class Person { void f() {} }
class Student extends Person { void f() {} }
```

So when I execute the following code:

```
Person p = new Student();
((Person) p).f();
```

Why is the `f()` function in the Student class called when the variable is cast as a Person? I understand why the `f()` function is called when it is just `p.f()`, but I guess I'm just confused to what exactly the cast does.

Comment: Try this pair of lines (from the description of ClassCastException): `Object x = new Integer(0); System.out.println((String)x);`

Comment: Ok. I thought that casting an object would change the object's type instead of the reference. I understand downcasting and upcasting, though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Casting an object has no effect on either the object itself or the reference to the object.  What it does is inform the Java verifier as to the new type to assume for the object.  But that assumption is only valid after the cast itself has been verified by checking for a proper superclass-subclass relationship.  This may be done at verify time (when the class is loaded, essentially), or it may be done dynamically on the individual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cornerstones of Object Oriented: Polymorphism. You have all kinds of Person entities each doing f() in its own way! It is the actual instance of the object and not what you cast it to that does f().

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert subtypes to Type this casting is always allowed in java however because instance is of subtype subtype methods will get executed.

You can check [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233902/java-rules-for-casting) for more information 
In Java there are two types of reference variable casting:

- **Downcasting**: If you have a reference variable that refers to a subtype object, you can assign it to a reference variable of the
  subtype. You must make an explicit cast to do this, and the result is
  that you can access the subtype's members with this new reference
  variable.
- **Upcasting**: You can assign a reference variable to a supertype reference variable explicitly or implicitly. This is an inherently
  safe operation because the assignment restricts the access
  capabilities of the new variable.

Yes, you need to implement the interface directly or indirectly to enable assigning your class object reference to the interface type.

Answer (score 1):

When invoking methods, it will be always executed on object type, not reference type due to ploymorphsim.

Answer (score 1):

The same method -- the one in Student -- will be called whether or not you've cast the Student to a Person.

Up-casting a reference (from subclass to superclass) serves no real function (and in fact will generally be a no-op internally).  Down-casting, on the other hand, tells the JVM that you believe the superclass to be of the specified subclass, and if it's not a cast error will be raised.

(I'll give gefei credit for pointing out an omission above:  The cast ALSO tells the compiler the type, and the compiler uses this information to know what methods and fields the object (supposedly) has.  This is not strictly necessary to compile a Java program to bytecodes, but it does allow the compiler to do the usual compile time validity checks.)

Comment: @gefei (Read the description of ClassCastException [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/).)

Comment: But the subject of your downvote was your claim that the JVM does not see the cast.  It does.

Comment: ok, you are right, when downcasting to a class which is not the actuall type of the object or its ancestor, then jvm throws an exception. i was just thinking in the context of binding.

Answer (score 0):

The upcasting is irrelevant here. The overridden method will always be called if present.

Answer (score 0):

The cast in your example is totally useless. The compiler knows that `p` is of type `Person`. More interesting would be a narrowing cast:

```
Person p = getPerson();
if (p instanceof Student) {
    Student s = (Student) p;
    // do something Student-specific with s
}
```

Casting reference types in Java does *not* change the nature of the object; it only tells the compiler what assumptions can be made about the object. At run time, the object's actual type is used to determine what method is called. (Note that this is not true of primitive types; casting an `int` to a `byte` will change the data.)