# Casting JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a new module for a project which should connect to a SQL database using a JDBC driver. I am required to implement a Connection Interface with method `getConnection()` which is of the return type `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection`. However, the JDBC driver returns a connection of the type `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`. Casting gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection cannot be cast to org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection
    at org.forgerock.opendj.virtual.JDBCConnectionFactory.getConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:105)
```

What would be the best way to obtain a connection of the type `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection` instead of the `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`?

The JDBCConnectionFactory class:

```
public class JDBCConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory{
    private final String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private Connection con = null;
    private String ConnectionUrl = "";
    private final String Host;
    private final int Port;
    private final String DbName;
    private final String UserName;
    private final String UserPass;

public JDBCConnectionFactory(final String host, final int port, final String dbName, final String userName, final String userPass) {
        this.Host = host;
        this.Port = port;
        this.DbName = dbName;
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.UserPass = userPass;
        this.ConnectionUrl="jdbc:mysql://"
                .concat(this.Host+":")
                .concat(this.Port+"/")
                .concat(this.DbName);

        try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
    }
```

The getConnection method:

```
@Override
    public org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection getConnection()throws ErrorResultException {
        try {

            con = DriverManager
                            .getConnection(this.ConnectionUrl,this.UserName,this.UserPass);

            org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection newcon = (org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection) con;
            System.out.println("Connection created.");
            return newcon;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return null;
            }


    }
```

Comment: You're creating a MySQL JDBC connection via a MySQL driver. Why would you think you'd get anything different ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew I don't expect anything different than com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection from the driver, I'm just looking for the best way to convert it to the type org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection.

Comment: So casting isn't a *conversion*. And I'm still suspicious that you're connecting to a MySQL database, and trying to interpret it as an LDAP server.

Comment: @BrianAgnew I'm making a module to convert LDAP client requests to SQL database queries against an underlying MySQL database. I just can't figure out how to get the right return type for getConnection() using the JDBC driver.

Comment: If you want to use a MySQL database as a store for directory services data, you must create your own implementation of `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection` and implement all of the methods in this interface yourself.  This implementation of `Connection` could take a MySQL database connection via a constructor parameter or a setter method, and that would be how you would do the 'conversion'.  A simple cast is not enough - the compiler cannot magically do all of this work for you.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Ok, thank you for sending me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer you cannot .Heres why

`org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection` **does not extend** `java.sql.Connection`

This should give you more info as what is allowed in Java

- [Java rules for casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233902/java-rules-for-casting)
- [Reference Type Casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)

Comment: I assume you mean "`com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection` does not extend `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection`".  Your statement as it is written now is utterly false.

Comment: Doesn't it extend ConnectionImpl, and *that* implements Connection ?

Comment: @Brian : Since org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection is an interface it must extend java.sql.Connection for the casting to work

Comment: @Luke: yep you are correct .Its a typo i have corrected.Thanks for catching though

Comment: @Sudhakar: what you have written is now correct, but it misses the point.  The point is that `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection`, which is what the `DriverManager.getConnection()` method call returns, does not implement `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection`, which is what the asker is trying to cast to.

Comment: @LukeWoodward : The OP was  expecting and type casting a java.sql.Connection to something else,hence the exception , i gave info about why its not possible. I would have answered `Adapter Pattern` if his question was about how to convert.

Comment: The point is not that the return type of the `DriverManager.getConnection` method is `java.sql.Connection`.  As `java.sql.Connection` and `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection` are both interfaces, it is possible (although unlikely) that `DriverManager.getConnection` could return an object that implements both.  In such a situation, no exception would be thrown.  The MySQL implementation of `java.sql.Connection` that `DriverManager.getConnection` actually returned in the asker's code above doesn't implement `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection`, and *that* is why the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JDBC API to create a LDAP connection. You should use the provided `org.forgerock.opendj.ldap` API to create one.

You are sure you need to connect to a SQL database and not a LDAP database?

Check this guide for connecting to a LDAP server and get the kind of connection you need:

[Getting OpenDJ LDAP SDK](http://opendj.forgerock.org/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-get-sdk.html)