# Cannot cast object to hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

My code:

```
Object res =  stub.call(sessionId, "sale.list", "11111");
HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) res;
```

Converting object into HashMap i got following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.util.HashMap;   
cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

Can anyone help me how to retrieve object data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast res to `HashMap` only if `stub.call(sessionId, "sale.list", "11111")` returns a `HashMap` object.

`[Ljava.lang.HashMap;` indicates that what you are getting is an array of hashMap and not a single HashMap.

Answer (score 7):

You are getting an array of hash maps, so cast to array:

```
HashMap[] maps = (HashMap[]) res;
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception message indicates that the `stub.call(...)` method is returning `HashMap[]` and not `HashMap`.

The "fix" is to do this:

```
  HashMap<String, String>[] maps = (HashMap<String, String>[]) res;
```

Or if you know that the array will contain exactly one element, then:

```
  HashMap<String, String> map = ((HashMap<String, String>[]) res)[0];
```

Unfortunately, both of these are going to give you warnings about an unchecked conversions. and the only way to avoid that is to use wildcard / raw types; e.g.

```
  HashMap<?, ?> map = ((HashMap<?, ?>[]) res)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object res =  stub.call(sessionId, "sale.list", "11111");
```

Now, if you know the above code returns a java.util.Map or atleast a java.util.HashMap, and it follows the same generics then you can cast it to a Map. Or the least, it should return a null.

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) res;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cast some thing to some other thing, you may know about java casting. In Java there are two types of reference variable casting.

**Downcasting**: If you have a reference variable that refers to a subtype object, you can assign it to a reference variable of the subtype. You must make an explicit cast to do this, and the result is that you can access the subtype's members with this new reference variable.

**Upcasting**: You can assign a reference variable to a supertype reference variable explicitly or implicitly. This is an inherently safe operation because the assignment restricts the access capabilities of the new variable.

I quote this from [Java rules for casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233902/java-rules-for-casting)

Answer (score 0):

Many objects can be successfully cast to a map like this:

```
 Map<T, U> map = (Map<T, U>) res;
```

but those objects have to be of a certain form. The generic form of res must be:

```
res = {
 field1:field1_value,
 field2:field2_value,
 field3:field3_value,
 .
 .
}
```

However, fieldx must be implicitly convertible to type T and fieldx_value must be implicitly convertible to type U.

Something like this:

```
res = {A, B, C, ....}
```

is not convertible to a map in the manner shown above. res needs to have key-value pairs. However, res may be convertible to an array of maps (having one element or multiple elements) that looks like this:

```
[ {0:{A, B, C, ....}} ], that is a Map<Integer, Res>[]
```

or like this:

```
[{0:A}, {1:B}, {2:C}], that is a Map<Integer, type<A>>[]
```

The trouble is, in either case, is the key of type T and the value of type U? Secondly, you have to explicitly create the two maps immediately above to achieve something deterministic. You can use Java Streams.

Comment: This doesn't apply to Java.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).