# Can Java cast anything?

Tags: java, object, casting, subclass

I've taken a year of java course at school and my understanding of casting is pretty limited.

The type of casting I understand is casting int to double. This makes sense; 1 would become 1.0

The type of casting I don't quite understand is:
casting a custom object (say `superRectangle`) to another customer object (eg, `myRectangle`). (this is assuming `myRectangle` is a subclass of `superRectangle`)
What happens to all the private or public fields associated with an instance of `superRectangle`? How does the program know this is a legit move? For all that matters I could've just casted an int to a string, and what is that supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/2233926/1759128

Comment: When do you need the cast? In functions' parameters you could try Java Generics

Comment: For casting remeber that the object truely *is* one thing and that never changed. For example a car wash takes a `Car` and washes it (it casts your `Honda` to `Car` and washes it) but its only "looking at it from that point of view", it still actually is a `Honda`. If it tried to cast that car to a `Ford` you'd get a runtime exception because what it really is is a `Honda`

Comment: Incidently casting and its cousin `instanceof` should be rare in your program. There is usually a better way to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, going from `int` to `double` isn't *casting*, but *conversion*. Casting is about reinterpreting the same, unchanged bit pattern in memory as belonging to another type. And this is precisely what casting reference types in Java boils down to: you have an object of some definite, unchangeable type, and you merely *look* at it as if it was an instance of one of its supertypes.

You will not be allowed to cast an `Integer` to a `String` because the latter is not the former's supertype. This is ensured at compile time and double-checked at runtime as well.

Answer (score 3):

Its known by the **Class Hierarchy** if they are in the same hierarchy then there is no issue with the casting at compile time.

`Integer` and `Double` are **siblings** and not in the same hierarchy so you can' say

```
Double d = (Double)(new Integer(4));// compile time error
```

Each sub-class know about its super-class as well.

Read more about [OOP: Class Hierarchy](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/JAVAcourse/ch3/s1.html)

Answer (score 2):

The casting only works if "superRectangle" is a "myRectangle" just currently being referenced as a superRectangle. You will get a casting exception at runtime, if it is not.

If we assume `MyRectangle` and `YourRectangle` both extend `SuperRectangle`...

This code will work:

```
SuperRectangle superRect = new MyRectangle();
MyRectangle castedMyRect = (MyRectangle)superRect;
```

This code will throw `ClassCastException`:

```
SuperRectangle superRect = new MyRectangle();
YourRectangle castedYourRect = (YourRectangle)superRect;
```