# How to get over this cast exception?

Tags: java, object, casting

I'm getting a cast error (cannot cast from string to station), how could I overcome this, as I will need you use startStation as a parameter in other methods:

```
Station startStation;
startStation = (Station)(view.getStartStation());
```

Here is the `Station` class:

```
    public class Station {

// The name of the station.
private String name;

public Station(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(
                "The name of a station may not be null");
    }
    this.name = name;
}
```

Here is my `getStartStation()` method:

```
 public String getStartStation() {
    return startStation.getText();
}
```

Comment: Please show us the definition of the `Station` class. And ideally the `getStartStation()` method too.

Comment: Please read this Casting Rules http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233902/java-rules-for-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latest edit shows that your class already has a suitable constructor. Change your code to:

```
Station startStation;
startStation = new Station(view.getStartStation());
```

or, more simply,

```
Station startStation = new Station(view.getStartStation());
```

Comment: THANKS! This works :-) Arrrgh been doing my head in for the last half an hour

Answer (score 5):

Just create a `Station` object by using the existing constructor:

```
Station startStation = new Station(view.getStartStation());
```

Comment: view.getStartStation is actually get a input from a textfield, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: So you must create a Station object from a string then (using a construction for example)

Comment: As I have tried casting it as a station in view.getStartStation() but still getting the cast error

Comment: @user3603183 if view.getStartStation() return a string, you can't cast it to a Station but, create a constructor with a String argument to create a Station object

Answer (score 1):

Or make station take a constructor argument of string, and create a new instance based on the string.

You could also use a factory, for station object creation.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot cast from string to station

The result of that method is a `string` data type. Try creating a new method to convert the string to Station data type. Station is not accepting the String data type values.

Otherwise it won't cast it.